# How does one prove a type of the form (a | b) in agda?

Tags: agda, dependent-type

In thinking about:

[In Agda is it possible to define a datatype that has equations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600007/in-agda-is-it-possible-to-define-a-datatype-that-has-equations)

I was playing with the following datatype:

```
data Int : Set where
    Z : Int
    S : Int -> Int
    P : Int -> Int
```

The above is a poor definition of Integers, and the answers in the above give a way around this.  However, one can define a reduction on the above Int type that might be useful.

```
normalize : Int -> Int
normalize Z = Z
normalize (S n) with normalize n
... | P m = m
... | m = S m
normalize (P n) with normalize n
... | S m = m
... | m = P m
```

The thing that needs to be proved is:

```
idempotent : (n : Int) -> normalize n \== normalize (normalize n)
```

When you expand the cases out, you get for example

```
idempotent (P n) = ?
```

The goal for the hole has type

```
(normalize (P n) | normalize n) \== normalize (normalize (P n) | normalize n)
```

And I haven't seen this "|" before, nor do I know how to produce a proof of a type involving them.  The proof needs to pattern match,for example,

```
idempotent (P n) with inspect (normalize n)
... (S m) with-\== = ?
... m with-\== = ?
```

But here the hole for the second case still has a "|" in it.  So I am a bit confused.

-------- EDIT ---------------

It would be helpful to prove a simpler statement:

```
normLemma : (n m : NZ) -> normalize n \== P m -> normalize (S n) \== m
```

The "on paper" proof is rather straightforward.  Assuming normalize n = P m, consider

```
normalize (S n) = case normalize n of
  P k -> k
  x -> S x
```

But normalize n is assumed to be P m, hence normalize (S n) = k.  Then k = m, since normalize n = P m = P k which implies m = k.  Thus normalize (S n) = m.

Comment: Your data definition is a bit broken. Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498428/types-containing-with-rewrite-clauses-in-agda-or-how-to-use-rewrite-instead-of) help? If it doesn't, I'll take a look into it.

Comment: I fixed the data definition -- that was a bit silly.  I will look at the link you posted in a bit.  Thanks!!

Comment: user3237465's answer actually made me think about the solution as well. I think I managed to find something a bit nicer: basically, the trick is to prove a lemma about normal forms (`norm` always returns either `s (s (s ... z))` or `p (p (p ... z))`). You can then easily prove that `norm` applied to something already in normal form does nothing and then use the lemma to prove idempotence. https://gist.github.com/vituscze/75acce9c8642c0f00c1c

Comment: @Vitus, after reading your comment, I found even more nicer solution: https://gist.github.com/flickyfrans/f2c7d5413b3657a94950#file-another-one

Comment: @user3237465: Great!

Comment: @Vitus, I switched to datatype instead of recursion. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: @user3237465: Nah, just add a new answer if you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User **Vitus** proposed to use normal forms.

If we have these two functions:

```
normalForm : ∀ n -> NormalForm (normalize n)
idempotent' : ∀ {n} -> NormalForm n -> normalize n ≡ n
```

then we can easily compose them to obtain the result we need:

```
idempotent : ∀ n -> normalize (normalize n) ≡ normalize n
idempotent = idempotent' ∘ normalForm
```

Here is the definition of normal forms:

```
data NormalForm : Int -> Set where
  NZ  : NormalForm Z
  NSZ : NormalForm (S Z)
  NPZ : NormalForm (P Z)
  NSS : ∀ {n} -> NormalForm (S n) -> NormalForm (S (S n))
  NPP : ∀ {n} -> NormalForm (P n) -> NormalForm (P (P n))
```

I.e. only terms like `S (S ... (S Z)...` and `P (P ... (P Z)...)` are in the normal form.

And proofs are rather straightforward:

```
normalForm : ∀ n -> NormalForm (normalize n)
normalForm  Z    = NZ
normalForm (S n) with normalize n | normalForm n
... | Z    | nf     = NSZ
... | S  _ | nf     = NSS nf
... | P ._ | NPZ    = NZ
... | P ._ | NPP nf = nf
normalForm (P n) with normalize n | normalForm n
... | Z    | nf     = NPZ
... | S ._ | NSZ    = NZ
... | S ._ | NSS nf = nf
... | P  _ | nf     = NPP nf

idempotent' : ∀ {n} -> NormalForm n -> normalize n ≡ n
idempotent'  NZ     = refl
idempotent'  NSZ    = refl
idempotent'  NPZ    = refl
idempotent' (NSS p) rewrite idempotent' p = refl
idempotent' (NPP p) rewrite idempotent' p = refl
```

The whole code: https://gist.github.com/flickyfrans/f2c7d5413b3657a94950#file-another-one

Comment: I really like the idea behind this answer.  Can you explain what the rewrite does?  I tried expanding it as per http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.PatternMatching
But it didn't work out as I expected.

Comment: @Jonathan Gallagher, the `rewrite` works just as described at the link in your message. Here is how the code looks with the expanded `rewrite`: http://lpaste.net/114337

Comment: Okay.  The proof I was getting was more involved.  http://lpaste.net/114345.  I guess "._" is special syntax that I don't understand.

Comment: @Jonathan Gallagher, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20682013/agda-why-am-i-unable-to-pattern-match-on-refl) should help. About dotted patterns you can read [here](http://oxij.org/note/BrutalDepTypes/) for example.

Answer (score 2):

```
idempotent : (n : Int) -> normalize (normalize n) ≡ normalize n
idempotent  Z    = refl
idempotent (S n) with normalize n | inspect normalize n
... | Z   |   _   = refl
... | S m | [ p ] = {!!}
... | P m | [ p ] = {!!}
```

Context in the first hole is

```
Goal: (normalize (S (S m)) | (normalize (S m) | normalize m)) ≡
      S (S m)
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
p : normalize n ≡ S m
m : Int
n : Int
```

`(normalize (S (S m)) | (normalize (S m) | normalize m)) ≡ S (S m)` is just an expanded version of `normalize (S (S m))`. So we can rewrite the context a bit:

```
Goal: normalize (S (S m)) ≡ S (S m)
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
p : normalize n ≡ S m
m : Int
n : Int
```

Due to the definition of the `normalize` function

```
normalize (S n) with normalize n
... | P m = m
... | m = S m
```

`normalize (S n) ≡ S (normalize n)`, if `normalize n` doesn't contain `P`s.

If we have an equation like `normalize n ≡ S m`, than `m` is already normalized and doesn't contain `P`s. But if `m` doesn't contain `P`s, so and `normalize m`. So we have `normalize (S m) ≡ S (normalize m)`.

Let's prove a little more general lemma:

```
normalize-S : ∀ n {m} -> normalize n ≡ S m -> ∀ i -> normalize (m ‵add‵ i) ≡ m ‵add‵ i
```

where ‵add‵ is

```
_‵add‵_ : Int -> ℕ -> Int
n ‵add‵  0      = n
n ‵add‵ (suc i) = S (n ‵add‵ i)
```

`normalize-S` states, that if `m` doesn't contain `P`s, than this holds:

```
normalize (S (S ... (S m)...)) ≡ S (S ... (S (normalize m))...)
```

Here is a proof:

```
  normalize-S : ∀ n {m} -> normalize n ≡ S m -> ∀ i -> normalize (m ‵add‵ i) ≡ m ‵add‵ i
  normalize-S  Z    ()    i
  normalize-S (S n) p     i with normalize n | inspect normalize n
  normalize-S (S n) refl  i | Z       |   _   = {!!}
  normalize-S (S n) refl  i | S m     | [ q ] = {!!}
  normalize-S (S n) refl  i | P (S m) | [ q ] = {!!}
  normalize-S (P n) p     i with normalize n | inspect normalize n
  normalize-S (P n) ()    i | Z       |   _     
  normalize-S (P n) refl  i | S (S m) | [ q ] = {!!}
  normalize-S (P n) ()    i | P _     |   _
```

Context in the first hole is

```
Goal: normalize (Z ‵add‵ i) ≡ Z ‵add‵ i
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
i  : ℕ
.w : Reveal .Data.Unit.Core.hide normalize n is Z
n  : Int
```

I.e. `normalize (S (S ... (S Z)...)) ≡ S (S ... (S Z)...)`. We can easily prove it:

```
normalize-add : ∀ i -> normalize (Z ‵add‵ i) ≡ Z ‵add‵ i
normalize-add  0      = refl
normalize-add (suc i) rewrite normalize-add i with i
... | 0     = refl
... | suc _ = refl
```

So we can fill the first hole with `normalize-add i`.

Context in the second hole is

```
Goal: normalize (S m ‵add‵ i) ≡ S m ‵add‵ i
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
i : ℕ
q : .Data.Unit.Core.reveal (.Data.Unit.Core.hide normalize n) ≡ S m
m : Int
n : Int
```

While `normalize-S n q (suc i)` has this type:

```
(normalize (S (m ‵add‵ i)) | normalize (m ‵add‵ i)) ≡ S (m ‵add‵ i)
```

Or, shortly, `normalize (S (m ‵add‵ i)) ≡ S (m ‵add‵ i)`. So we need to replace `S m ‵add‵ i` with `S (m ‵add‵ i)`:

```
inj-add : ∀ n i -> S n ‵add‵ i ≡ S (n ‵add‵ i)
inj-add n  0      = refl
inj-add n (suc i) = cong S (inj-add n i)
```

And now we can write

```
  normalize-S (S n) refl  i | S m | [ q ] rewrite inj-add m i = normalize-S n q (suc i)
```

Context in the third hole is

```
Goal: normalize (m ‵add‵ i) ≡ m ‵add‵ i
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
i : ℕ
q : .Data.Unit.Core.reveal (.Data.Unit.Core.hide normalize n) ≡
    P (S m)
m : Int
n : Int
```

`normalize-P n q 0` gives us `normalize (S m) ≡ S m` where `normalize-P` is dual of `normalize-S` and has this type:

```
  normalize-P : ∀ n {m} -> normalize n ≡ P m -> ∀ i -> normalize (m ‵sub‵ i) ≡ m ‵sub‵ i
```

We can apply `normalize-S` to something, that has type `normalize (S m) ≡ S m`: `normalize-S (S m) (normalize-P n q 0) i`. This expression has precisely the type we want. So we can write

```
  normalize-S (S n) refl  i | P (S m) | [ q ] = normalize-S (S m) (normalize-P n q 0) i
```

The fourth hole is similar to the third:

```
  normalize-S (P n) refl  i | S (S m) | [ q ] = normalize-S (S m) (normalize-S n q 0) i
```

There is a problem with this holes: Agda doesn't see, that `normalize-S (S m) _ _` terminates, since `S m` is not syntactically smaller than `S n`. It's possible however to convience Agda by using well-founded recursion.

Having all this stuff we can easily proof the `idempotent` theorem:

```
idempotent : (n : Int) -> normalize (normalize n) ≡ normalize n
idempotent  Z    = refl
idempotent (S n) with normalize n | inspect normalize n
... | Z   |   _   = refl
... | S m | [ p ] = normalize-S n p 2
... | P m | [ p ] = normalize-P n p 0
idempotent (P n) with normalize n | inspect normalize n
... | Z   |   _   = refl
... | S m | [ p ] = normalize-S n p 0
... | P m | [ p ] = normalize-P n p 2
```

Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/flickyfrans/f2c7d5413b3657a94950
There are both versions: with the `{-# TERMINATING #-}` pragma and without.

**EDIT**

`idempotent` is simply

```
idempotent : ∀ n -> normalize (normalize n) ≡ normalize n
idempotent n with normalize n | inspect normalize n
... | Z   |   _   = refl
... | S _ | [ p ] = normalize-S n p 1
... | P _ | [ p ] = normalize-P n p 1
```

Comment: By the way, it's better to locally declare which functions shouldn't be termination checked (I think the pragma is `{-# NO_TERMINATION_CHECK #-}` or, in newer versions of Agda, you can just assert that the function is terminating with `{-# TERMINATING #-}`), instead of turning it off for whole module.

Comment: @Vitus, mm, I'm not sure, if it's better for all cases. I'd rather prefer to mark whole file as "untrustable", since if some function is not terminating, than the whole proof is wrong. But since all functions in my code are provably terminating, yes, it's better to use `{-# TERMINATING #-}`. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Agda picks it up regardless with the `--safe` flag, so I wouldn't be worried.